# Make one reference and load the other automatically (Entity Reference)

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type "songs", lets say a node has a reference to 4 or 5 other nodes.
What I want is when I create a new node, I just need to make a reference to one node and the other 4 nodes will be loaded automatically.

Is that possible?

Comment: Is this drupal 8 or 7? Also are you creating new 'song' nodes in code? Or are you making them in the drupal menus?

Comment: I'm using drupal 7 ! i making them in the drupal menus (the simple way !! )   thank you

Comment: How are you referencing them, and what are you using them for? Do you have a section displaying 'related songs'?

Comment: Ok ! I have a content type "songs" , i have two type of songs "original" and "remix"  , and when i create new remix i make reference to the original song , and every song have multiple remixes ! so what I want exactly is ..when I make remix 1 to original A , and make remix 2 to original A also ! the remix1 & remix 2 make reference automaticly ! without need to make reference one by one ! hope you understand me  thank you

Comment: Do you just want every remix referring to a specific song to show up on a song's page?

Comment: yes ! i want the remixes referring automaticly to to each other ! let me explain that i have an original track " A " have reference with 4 remixes " 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 " , so when I add a new remix "5" i just need to make reference with original track " A " and the other remixes "1.2.3.4" load automaticly without need to reference them one by one ! hope you understand me now ... thank you Matt

Comment: You might want to give this a shot. https://www.drupal.org/project/eva It's a module that lets you attach a view to a content type. There's also a video tutorial on it. You could possibly create a view that displays all content that has an entity reference value of the current node and then use EVA to attach that view to the song content type.

Comment: I use Drupal 8 myself, and haven't used that module so I don't know if that will work for sure, but it looks like that might be a possible solution.

Comment: If that doesn't work, there are other ways but they involve making a template file and digging into some code.

Comment: ok ! i know how eva does work ! but my problem is not in how display the referenced node . but my problem is a short way to add value in entity reference field (a short way)

Comment: load refenced nodes by add a one value in entity reference field .. !! thanks Matt

Comment: Are you talking about on the page where you edit or add the content? Instead of the page that shows the node?

Comment: If that's the case why would you need to make the song point to all the remixes? Couldn't you just have one field on the remix that is a reference to a song? And then the song would just load every node that has that song as a reference? That way you wouldn't have put in every remix in the song, you'd just have to put the song in the remixes. Does that make sense?

Comment: In other words you'd have a Song content type, and a Remix content type. The remix content type would have a reference field pointing to the one song it's a remix of. And the song content type would not have a reference field at all.

Comment: What is your reference field is called? I mean what is its machine name?

Answer (score 0):

Broadly if your node reference is required your user must to fill it on node creation. So you could try to use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) or in the form layer you could have your submit handler to deal with that. Once you get the reference chosen by the user you would need to retrieve the other 4 related references that will be also added as siblings in the multi valued node reference field.
By another hand if you want to make all of this visible in the form before it gets submitted you could use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) (in case you don't have your own [hook_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_form/7.x)) to add a [behavior](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/converting-drupal-6-modules-to-drupal-7/converting-6x-modules-to-7x#drupal_behaviors) to the node reference field form element and if it has just a checkbox widget you could simply automatically check the other nodes to be referenced using the behavior to react the check box that has been checked.